# Multi dimensional (2d better 3d) scatter-plot with different errorbars in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, scatter-plot

I am trying to program scatterplot with specific errorbars. The only build in function i found is

```
errorbar()
```

but this only enables me to make a 2d plot with errorbars in y direction. What i am asking for is a method to plot this with errorbars in x and y direction.

At the end my goal is to make a 3D-scatter-plot with 3 errorbars. 
Perfect would be if the resulting image would be a 3d-plot with 3d geometric shapes (coordinate x,y,z with expansion in the dimension proportional to the errorbars) as 'marker'.

I found this page while searching the internet: http://code.izzid.com/2007/08/19/How-to-make-a-3D-plot-with-errorbars-in-matlab.html
But unfortunately they use only one errorbar. 

My data is set of 6 arrays each containing either the x,y or z coordinate or the specific standard derivation i want to show as errorbar.

Comment: I suggest you compare the FEX submission [HERRORBAR](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3963-herrorbar) to the code inside `errorbar`. It looks like `HERRORBAR` is directly adapted from `errorbar`, if you look at the changes, you might learn how to adapt it for a third dimension.

Comment: going to do that. For my best case szenario, you got any idea how to make the markers to 3d objects?

Comment: If you take a closer look at the plot3d_errorbars, it draws a line from [x,y,z+e] to [x,y,z-e]. You have to extend this to all three dimensions.

Comment: You already posted a link showing you how to do that, you just need to adapt that code to be in the other two directions as well. In fact the code you posted is far simpler than `errorbar` and I think you should have a go at adapting it and then post here when you get stuck.

Comment: I have an idea how i could solve the problem, but i ain't sure if it would work and if so how i should program it. In my idea couldn't i plot an errorbar(x,y,e_y) then take the graph transform it back into datapoints and change the coordinates. So that i then plot errorbar(y_new,x,ex)?  For this to work i would have to know how matlab saves/computes the errorbar()-function and if its possible to change it back into a data-matrix. I thought this could work with handles. Any hints, comments, ideas or reasons why it shouldn't work are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the function I posted, it creates error bars in all three diections...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [code you posted](http://code.izzid.com/2007/08/19/How-to-make-a-3D-plot-with-errorbars-in-matlab.html) looks very easy to adapt to draw all three error bars. Try this (note that I adapted it also so that you can change the shape and colour etc of the plots as you normally would by using `varargin`, e.g. you can call `plot3d_errorbars(...., '.r')`:

```
function [h]=plot3d_errorbars(x, y, z, ex, ey, ez, varargin)

% create the standard 3d scatterplot
hold off;
h=plot3(x, y, z, varargin{:});

% looks better with large points
set(h, 'MarkerSize', 25);
hold on

% now draw the vertical errorbar for each point
for i=1:length(x)
        xV = [x(i); x(i)];
        yV = [y(i); y(i)];
        zV = [z(i); z(i)];

        xMin = x(i) + ex(i);
        xMax = x(i) - ex(i);
        yMin = y(i) + ey(i);
        yMax = y(i) - ey(i);
        zMin = z(i) + ez(i);
        zMax = z(i) - ez(i);

        xB = [xMin, xMax];
        yB = [yMin, yMax];
        zB = [zMin, zMax];

        % draw error bars
        h=plot3(xV, yV, zB, '-k');
        set(h, 'LineWidth', 2);
        h=plot3(xB, yV, zV, '-k');
        set(h, 'LineWidth', 2);
        h=plot3(xV, yB, zV, '-k');
        set(h, 'LineWidth', 2);
end
```

Example of use:

```
x = [1, 2];
y = [1, 2];
z = [1, 2];
ex = [0.1, 0.1];
ey = [0.1, 0.5];
ez = [0.1, 0.3];

plot3d_errorbars(x, y, z, ex, ey, ez, 'or')
```

Comment: yeah your adaption works just fine. Thanks a lot and its much better than mine. I just copied the for loop 2 times and rotated the variables. Also getting the same results, but with much more lines and loops. So thx a lot. I have no idea about rights, but maybe you should refer inside your code to the link or the 'programmer' so that others who copy your code don't get problems.

Comment: @TheMinion Added a link

Comment: I wasn't talking about a link to the code, that is already done in my question, but about copyrights. Don't know since i found the code on the file sharing from mathworks, but if someone sees this forum copies it and doesn't refer to the 'real' author which was just adapted for 3D from you. He could get problems.

Comment: @TheMinion I think a link is fine